# orientation of heterodyne products

Tags: electromagnetism

Let us take two man-made propagating polarized coherent RF waves at frequencies F1 and F2 of equal amplitude and direction. Assuming vertical polarization is assigned as 0 degrees, let F1 be at 0 degrees and F2 be at 10 degrees. Let these waves interact by heterodyning to produce F3 = F2- F1 and also F4 = F2 + F1 .  Are the heterodyned products F3 and F4 polarized, and if so what is the angle of polarization in this example?

Comment: orthogonal polarizations mix independently from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are both polarised (there will be mixing). 
The interfered wave will have both components 
$$
\vec E(\vec r,t)=\vec E_1(\vec r,t)+\vec E_2(\vec r,t)=E_1(\vec r)\hat e_1e^{i\phi_1}e^{-i2 \pi f_1 t}+E_2(\vec r)\hat e_2 e^{i\phi_2}e^{-i 2\pi f_2t} \,,
$$

where $\hat e_1$ and $\hat e_1$ are the unit polarisation vectors.

How much of mixing can be reflected in the intensity after the interference where there will be a term

$$
(\hat e_1\cdot\hat e_2)=|\hat e_1||\hat e_2|\cos(\theta)=\cos(\theta),
$$
where for your case $\theta=10°$.